# Trouble outputting PHP text

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be having issue outputting a line of PHP.

```
<?php
    include 'db_connect.php';
    {
        $query = "SELECT INSERT_DATE,LINE_TEXT FROM DATA_TAB order by RAND() LIMIT 1";
    }
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        mysql_close($con);
 ?>

<table >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><?php
             $insert_date = strtotime($row['INSERT_DATE']);
             echo date("j F Y", $insert_date); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><?php 
             $line_text = $row['LINE_TEXT'];
             echo $line_text; ?></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

The output of $line_text doesn't appear to be displaying. Any ideas?

Comment: `db_connect.php` = ?

Comment: and you're most likely getting a parse error http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and you closed your connection too early.

Comment: Your braces `{ ... }` seem to have been misplaced. You need them at the `while`, not where you define a string.

Comment: insert_date is working, so surely it's some error in the second table row?